# Email writing- quotations/quotes, such (an) application(s), etc

Tags: email

This is a part of my email:

> I would like to seek your approval to accept my submission of the purchase requisition form with 3 written quotations instead of 6 written quotes. Please consider granting an approval for such application.

How to improve it?
for example:

- Should I write '3 written quotations instead of 6 written quotes'?
- Should I use 'such application'?

Comment: Who are you emailing?

Comment: I am emailing to my superior

Comment: Do you seriously spend your day "working" by formulating these incredibly wordy emails.

Comment: Should be a journalist, get paid by the word... Otherwise be succinct and clear - the answer is a good example. Then consider adding a statistical analysis of the “cost” spread shown by the 6 submissions compared to the spread shown by the three most commonly chosen companies - perhaps over the past year or 3 or 5...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

> I would like to seek your approval to accept my submission of the purchase requisition form with 3 written quotations instead of 6 written quotes. Please consider granting an approval for such application.

I'd do something like this:

> Would it be possible for purchase authorizations to be granted with just three written quotes instead of six?

I would then present reasons why I think three should be sufficient instead of six. eg. maybe because of how much time the extra three takes, maybe 95% of all authorized purchases were made with one of the first three vendors vs the last three, etc.